# RestKit - Path Matching with Query Strings

Tags: objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a request that looks like this:

```
/products?page=:page&perPage=:perPage
```

How can I structure my path matcher so that it will find these paths when calling

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] cancelAllObjectRequestOperationsWithMethod:RKRequestMethodGET matchingPathPattern:@"/products"];
```

This doesn't seem to match on this pattern.  How can I set up my `matchingPathPattern` argument to match those requests?

Answer (score 0):

I generally create named route. Reskit router comes with many different helper methods that will simplify the tasks in many ways. Create named route like this,

```
#define ProductsRoute  @"ProductsRoute"

RKRoute *productsRoute = [RKRoute routeWithName:ProductsRoute pathPattern:@"/products?page=:page&perPage=:perPage" method:RKRequestMethodGET];
```

Add the route to routeSet,

```
 [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeSet] addRoute:productsRoute];
```

Now, lets create a helper method which will cancel the request to the route if it comes to certain named route,

```
- (void)cancelRequestToUrlWithRouteName:(NSString*)routeName{
 RKRoute *route = [[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] router] routeSet] routeForName:routeName];
  [self cancelAllRequestWithMethod:route.method matchingPath:route.pathPattern];
}
```

Then call it whenever you want to cancel request to certain url,

```
[self cancelRequestToUrlWithRouteName:ProductsRoute];
```

I hope this works in your case as well.
Note I have not shown adding the responseDescriptors to objectManager. You would add response descriptor normally and the paginator mapping as you have been using it.

Comment: Have you tried this with parameters in the URL query? SoKit generally doesn't handle any parameters in the query section.

Comment: @Wain ya I wasn't quite sure how to apply this with my case.  Is there any way to wildcard my cancel so that it will cancel calls to /products but not other calls that may be outstanding?

Comment: Path patterns are wildcard by their nature, but I don't think it will work with query parameters...